# Parsing data from multiple URLS php

Tags: php, html, mysql, parsing, phpmyadmin

I want to parse data from this link: http://plan.regenbogen-gesamtschule.de/vertretung/lehrer/subst_001.htm which refreshes every 15 second with a new page, once it reaches the last page it starts again so it is an endless loop and the number of pages varies every day currently it has 4 pages (subst_001.htm, subst_002.htm, subst_003.htm, subst_004.htm)

My script should get get data from all the links and store in to my database. But I think I have a small mistake because it is only getting the data from the first URL (subst_001.htm) actually it should get data from all URLS.

Here is my script:

```html
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","konhostc_rges");
 mysqli_query($conn,"Delete from timetable2");
$startUrl="subst_001.htm";
function getData($url) {
 global $startUrl,$conn;
$html = file_get_contents('http://plan.regenbogen-gesamtschule.de/vertretung/lehrer/'.$url);

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$meta = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('meta');
$metaUrl = explode("=",$meta[4]->attributes->getNamedItem('content')->nodeValue);
 $nexUrl = $metaUrl[1];
 //print_r($meta[4]->attributes->getNamedItem('content')->nodeValue); exit; 
 $month = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$monthExp = explode(" ",$month->nodeValue);
 $date = $monthExp[0];
$day = $monthExp[1];

$tables = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('table');

$domRows = $tables[2]->getElementsByTagName('td');


$i=0; //colms
$y=0; //rows
foreach($domRows as $domRow)
{
 

    $data[$y][] = $domRow->nodeValue;
    if($i === 8) {
        $i = 0;
        $y++;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }

}
 


//Converting array to JSON
$JSON = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);



foreach($data as $row) {
 $vertr = $row[0];
 $std = $row[1];
 $klasse = $row[2];
 $raum = $row[3];
 $art = $row[4];
 $fach = $row[5];
 $lehr = $row[6];
 $bemerkung = $row[7];
 $Neu = $row[8];
 $date_timeTable=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
 mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO timetable2 (vertr,std,klasse,raum,art,fach,lehr,bemerkung,Neu,pageName,date_timeTable,day_timeTable) VALUES ('$vertr','$std','$klasse','$raum','$art','$fach','$lehr','$bemerkung','$Neu','$url','$date_timeTable','$day') ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}



if(trim($nexUrl)!=$startUrl) {
 getData($nexUrl);
}

}
getData($startUrl);
```

Here is my database structure:

```html
CREATE TABLE `timetable2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `vertr` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `std` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `klasse` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `raum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `art` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fach` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lehr` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bemerkung` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Neu` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pageName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_timeTable` date NOT NULL,
  `day_timeTable` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You call it, but the second, and the forth page (subst_002.htm, subst_004.htm) has only 2 table element, and the first, and third (subst_001.htm, subst_003.htm) has 3 table element.

This means your code gets fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on
>   null in index.php on line 22

This line:

```
$domRows = $tables[2]->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

So you should check which is the last table element, before you get it. Like this:

```
$domRows = $tables[sizeof($tables)-1]->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

This method you will get the last table element. By the way, maybe you should check to exists any table element, and if not, the function need to return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how do I return the function?

Comment: For example simple return; Because if the site don't have any table, the code cannot do anything.

Comment: Can you maybe modify the code and show I not very experienced in it i am new?

Comment: You should just write an if, before define $domRows: if(sizeof($tables) < 1) return FALSE;